# Load testing on activemq server

Tags: load-testing

Did anyone working on load testing on activemq?

Activemq(client) installed in different machines and request (Jms-text file encrypted) will be send to server using tcp protocol and activemq(server side) will receive request and response will be delivered to respective client.

Scenario: I would like to do load test on server side when 100 clients send requests to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need a JMS client capable of sending messages to ActiveMQ using multiple threads.

There are several tools available on the market which you can use in order to conduct the load on the JMS endpoints, for example:

- [Gatling](http://gatling.io/): [JMS](http://gatling.io/docs/current/jms/)
- [The Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/): [Java Message Service - Queue Sender](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/script-gallery.html#jmssender.py)
- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/): [Building a JMS Topic Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-topic-test-plan.html)

See [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) guide which highlights the main features of the aforementioned tools, contains sample test scripts, reports and comparison matrix.

Comment: i tried to use Jmeter with publisher and subscriber, It succeed only everything in  local machine whit jndi.properties file,i would like to use subscriber and publisher with different machine IPs and tcp protocol also not local address, is there anyway to configure?  Tried Gatling also but it working with only browser recording which is not my requirement.